# page reference code coverage

Tags: unit-test

suggest me how to cover page reference in test class.

```
public PageReference selectedPricingReq(){
        system.debug('-----> acceptedPRID: '+acceptedPRID);
        Pricing_Request__c prcReqObj = [select id, Pricing_Status__c, Price__c from Pricing_Request__c where id=:acceptedPRID limit 1];
        prcReqObj.Pricing_Status__c = 'Accepted';
        prcReqObj.Price__c = pricingInt;
        update prcReqObj;
        //Update Opp here
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/PricingSubmission?id='+pricingTask.Id+'&sfdc.override=1');
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure there is a Pricing Request record meeting the SQL criteria
2. If needed set the value of acceptedPRID - How you do it depends on the flow of your controller
3. Using the controller you instantiated in your test method call the method selectedPricingReq();

   ```
   PageReference pr = {variableforclass}.selectedPricingReq();
   ```
4. Assert that your returned URL is as expected

   ```
    system.assertEquals({variableforclass}.acceptedPRID, pr.getParameters().get('id'))
   ```